# Can chemnum replace TMP-Tags in any eps file, e.g. Origin? If so, how?

Tags: eps, psfrag, chemnum

I'm using Origin and TeXStudio on Windows 10 to plot several graphs for a Lab report. It would be extremely helpful, if chemnum could replace compounds' TMP-Tags in Origin's exported eps-files (here inside legend next to graph, see attachment) like it does in ChemDraw's eps-schemes. Apparently it is not possible by just using the TMP-labeled Origin eps-files, even though it shows up as clear text, if opened in an editor. How I can achieve this?
Thank you in advance!

I'm running MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4535 (1.40.13) and txs:///latex | txs:///dvips | txs:///ps2pdf | txs:///view-pdf as compiler commands in TeXStudio.

eps-file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nscrtatpd4z6i95/origintest.eps?dl=0

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scrhack} % fixes koma float warning

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{chemnum}  
\usepackage{chemscheme}         

\begin{document}
Compounds \cmpd{aichtsc}, \cmpd{znclaichtsc}, \cmpd{znbraichtsc}
\begin{figure}
\replacecmpd{aichtsc}\replacecmpd{znclaichtsc}\replacecmpd{znbraichtscs}
\includegraphics{origintest}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The real question is: can `psfrag` replace text in EPS files created by Origin? `chemnum` doesn't do any anything with the EPS file. Instead it loads `psfrag` and passes the task to its `\psfrag{eps text}{LaTeX code}` command.

Sadly, the minimal example using your EPS file seems to suggest that the answer is no:

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}

\begin{document}

\psfrag{TMP1}{xxx}
\includegraphics{origintest.eps}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is no replacement. However, this is not an unknown problem:

- [psfrag doesn't find labels in eps file](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=8105), a question on www.latex-community.org from 2010 with no solution
- [Origin Graphen und psfrag](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/de.comp.text.tex/origin$20psfrag%7Csort:relevance/de.comp.text.tex/OEME6D-g_7U/Sk0k7fMiuzgJ), a question on de.comp.text.tex from 2003 with no solution
- [Origin Graphen und psfrag](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/de.comp.text.tex/hRjKgkDonCw), a question on de.comp.text.tex from 2009 which has some hacky solution

It seems that Origin redefines some EPS function/procedure (whatever the correct name is) called `xs` in a way that `psfrag` cannot find the text any more.

The “solution” [posted on d.c.t.t](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/de.comp.text.tex/hRjKgkDonCw/2zY8hJJdd_EJ) is this:

```
sed -r -e "s/\)\[(([0-9])+ )+\] xs/\) show/g" in.eps > out.eps
```

That is, in the EPS change the line

```
(TMP1)[44 60 49 41 ] xs
```

into

```
(TMP1) show
```

and similar for the other text tags (or at least the ones you want to replace), either by hand or somewhat automated with the above sed call.

Afterwards the above example gives

[image]